# echo starts a sub-shell in a parallel process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my construct (just an example):

```
echo -e "hello: [$(cat file.txt)]"
```

In 90% cases it works OK and outputs (`foo` is in `file.txt`):

```
hello: [foo]
```

But in 10% cases I see (I don't know when and why exactly it's happening):

```
hello: []
foo
```

Why it's happening?

ps. In reality my code looks like:

```
STDERR=$(mktemp /tmp/bash-XXXX);
{ something } 2> >( tail -100 | tee $STDERR );
CODE=$?;
if [ $CODE != 0 ]; then
  echo -e "ERROR ${CODE}: \"$(cat ${STDERR})\"";
fi
rm -f ${STDERR}
```

Comment: Do you see this with that exact code, or is `cat` a stand-in for some other command? This should never, ever happen as written.

Comment: It's exactly `cat` with a file name, nothing else. I'm also very puzzled...

Comment: `for i in {0..10000}; do echo -e "hello: [$(cat file.txt)]"; done` For me, this worked OK the 100% of the cases

Comment: Is the file in a slow access media?

Comment: No, it's a normal file. I tried `$(sleep 1; cat file.txt)`, but still in most cases it works fine

Comment: some variety of 'experimental' linux (or bash) maybe that is doing what your title says?

Comment: Can you try cat -v in case there's some non-printable cursor positioning characters in your file?

Comment: I've posted my real-life code above, maybe it will help..

Comment: File content is exactly the same every time.

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes, `{ something }` might exit with a non-zero error code, yet not produce any output on `stderr` (or `std::cerr`, whichever)? That would easily explain what you're seeing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a race condition here.

```
tail -100 | tee $STDERR
```

is created, but most probably sleeps on the fifo (since it is still empty then). You programs writes to fifo ('something') but the fifo has buffers, so it writes all and continues. Then at some unspecific time the tail/tee is woken up - sometimes too late: That means $STDERR is still empty when cat reads it.

How to fix it: You can't easily synchronize on tee/tail having finished. Use

```
{ something; } 2>&1 | tail ... | tee
```

You need some other way to telegraf $? out of {something}. I'll come back on this.

- One way is, to set

  set -o pipefail

  so that every failing component in the pipline sets the exit status of the pipeline.
- Another way is to query the *array* PIPESTATUS (see bash(1)).

Hope this helps

Comment: I believe `{ something } 2> >( tail -100 | tee $STDERR ); wait` will also work.

Comment: I really ran this program and it is instructive to put sleeps at various points.

Comment: @Swiss: No. Wait waits for 'jobs' not any background processes. And yes: I simply tried it: Didn't work.

Comment: `wait` with no parameters should wait for all child processes. It should act a a barrier to allow everything to sync before $STDERR is used. Not sure why it's failing in this instance. I'll try to  dig into it.

Comment: "wait with no parameters should wait for all child processes". The documentation certainly suggests this, bu somehow experiment shows, it's not like this. Just introduce a sleep 5 before the tee (and put sleep/tee in {}).

Comment: "I'll try to dig into it" => I'd certainly be interested in the result. Might be a bash bug. Bash(1) is silent about this.

Comment: I did some testing. It appears that the `wait` is working correctly, since all child processes are finished before the script continues past it. However, there seems to be some kind of file handle related issue here. Running `sync` before the `$(cat $STDERR)` resolves the issue. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36963/discussion-between-swiss-and-m-e-l)

Comment: `sync; wait;` right after `CODE=$?` fixed the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: WARNING: "sync; wait; right after CODE=$? fixed the problem" - I'd like to point out to you, that this is probably mostly due to the delay / task switch introduces by wait/sync. A 'sleep 1' would have done as well. The problem will just occur less frequently, but will not have been fixed. Experiments so far (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36963/discussion-between-swiss-and-m-e-l) indicate that 'wait' does not wait on process created by process substitution.